# How can I use PowerShell to upload a list template (stp file)?

Tags: 2010, powershell, file-upload, list-template

I need to script the creation of data in SharePoint, and part of this requires that I upload a slide library list template using PowerShell. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8):

WebDav might work for others, but I found a way to do it using the SharePoint object model. (I used the folders indicated by Steve B--thanks.)

```
$site = get-spsite "http://myteam.lab/sites/team"
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
$spFolder = $web.getfolder("List Template Gallery")
$spfilecollection = $spfolder.files
$file = get-item c:\temp\MyTemplate.stp
$spfilecollection.Add("_catalogs/lt/MyTemplate.stp", $file.OpenRead(), $true)
```

I saw the template in the "Create" page, so everything seemed to work ok.

Answer (score 5):

You can cheat using Webdav :

```
Copy-Item 'yourTemplate.stp' '\\yourspwebapp\DavWWWRoot\sites\yoursitecoll\_catalogs\lt'
```

[edit] according your comment, here is a way to find the correct url.

1. Navigate using the browser to the list template catalog list. The link should look like : http://yourwebapp/sites/yoursitecoll/_catalogs/lt
2. as it is a document library, you can, from the ribbon's tab "Library", click on `Open in windows explorer`
3. an windows explorer windows pop ups, but with "http://" address.
4. Right click in the window, click properties, and you will find the actual address.

This worked for me, with a SP application having a custom AAM (yourspwebapp is not the hostname, but a virtual hostname). I checked locally... did you want to do this remotely ?

[Edit2] if installing Webdav is an issue on your server, you can use the following snippet :

```
$wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$file = (Get-Item '.\New Text Document.txt')
$dest = "http://yourspwebapp/sites/yoursitecoll/_catalogs/lt"
$wc.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$wc.UploadFile($dest +"/" + $file.Name, $file.FullName)
```

Or you can use the sp OM, as [Jimmarq](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15322/how-can-i-use-powershell-to-upload-a-list-template-stp-file/15327#15327) suggests

Comment: Hmm. I'm getting WebDav errors. I can't even map a drive to My Site. I must have a problem doing this from a 2008 R2 box.

Comment: I'm also running on a 2008 R2 box

Comment: When I click "Open with Exporer" I get an error message saying "Your client does not support opening this list with Windows Explorer." I'm guessing I'm missing either office components, or the Desktop Experience feature.

Comment: so this is another issue. Maybe this can help : http://mcgeeky.blogspot.com/2010/02/your-client-does-not-support-opening.html or http://blogs.technet.com/b/seanearp/archive/2010/07/08/your-client-does-not-support-opening-this-list-with-windows-explorer.aspx

Answer (score 1):

To add to this, if you would like to add the list template to all of your site collections, use this instead...

```
$GetSiteCollections = Get-SPSite -Limit ALL
## Add the List Template to the all the Site Collections
foreach($GetSiteCollection in $GetSiteCollections)
{
$web = $GetSiteCollection.OpenWeb();
$spfolder = $web.getfolder("_catalogs\lt")
$spfileCollection = $spfolder.Files
$file = Get-Item c:\Templates\MyListTemplate.stp
$spfileCollection.Add("MyListTemplate.stp", $file.OpenRead(), $true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the below function which uploads the list template and also creates a list based on that.

**Explanation of Parameters**:

1. `$rooturl`: its the url of the root web
2. `$listCreationUrl`: is the url in which you would want to create a list
3. `$listName`: Name of the list as you wish
4. `$listTemplateFileUrl`: file path where the list template .stp file is located on your machine
5. `$listTemplateName`: Important, What ever name was given while saving list as a template.

**Function**:

```
function UploadAndCreate-CustomListTemplate()
{
param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$rooturl,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$listCreationUrl,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$listName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$listTemplateFileUrl,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$listTemplateName
    )

    try
    {
        # Adding the PowerShell Snapin
        Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"

        # Get the SiteURL
        $site = get-spsite($rooturl)

        # Get the root web
        $web = $site.RootWeb

        # Get the list template gallery
        $spLTG = $web.getfolder("List Template Gallery")

        # Get the list template gallery Collection
        $spcollection = $spLTG.files

        # Get the custom list template file
        $Templatefile = get-item $listTemplateFileUrl

        # Add the custom list template file to gallery
        $titleHashTbl = @{}
        $titleHashTbl.Add("Title", $listTemplateName)
        $folderListTemplate = "_catalogs/lt/" + $listTemplateName + ".stp"
        $spcollection.Add($folderListTemplate, $Templatefile.OpenRead(),$titleHashTbl,$true)
        Write-Host "Custom Template Uploaded to List Template Gallery Successfully"

        Write-Host "Creating the List based on the Template"
        # Get the custom list templates
        $CustomlistTemplates = $site.GetCustomListTemplates($web)

        #Create the custom list using template
        $site = Get-SPWeb $listCreationUrl
        $site.Lists.Add($listName, $listName, $CustomlistTemplates[$listTemplateName])
        Write-Host "Based on the template List Created"
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host ("Error while creating list. Error -->> " + $_.Exception.Message) -ForegroundColor Red
    }

}
```

**Usage**:

```
$rootUrl = "http://somesite.com"
$url = "http://somesite.com" #Or http://somesite.com/subsite
$listName = "Some List"
$listTemplateFileUrl = "d:\whatever"
$listTemplateName = "List Template Name"


UploadAndCreate-CustomListTemplate $rootUrl $url $listName $listTemplateFileUrl $listTemplateName
```

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fromthefield/2014/02/19/office-365-powershell-script-to-upload-files-to-a-document-library-using-csom/) shows you how to upload files to a document library using CSOM.

What the script does:

1. Connects to your sharepoint site
2. Loads the document library into which the .stp files have to be
   uploaded.
3. Traverses the folder that contains your .stp files & uploads them to the document library

Here is the script:

```
# Specify tenant admin and site URL
$User = "admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$SiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site"
$Folder = "C:\FilesToUpload" # folder that contains the .stp files
$DocLibName = "List Template Gallery"; # This is where you want to upload your files

# Add references to SharePoint client assemblies and authenticate to Office 365 site – required for CSOM
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter your password" -AsSecureString

# Bind to site collection
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User, $Password)
$Context.Credentials = $Creds

# Retrieve list
$List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($DocLibName)
$Context.Load($List)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

# Upload files from folder
Foreach ($File in (dir $Folder -File))
{
    $FileStream = New-Object IO.FileStream($File.FullName,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
    $FileCreationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
    $FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $true
    $FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $FileStream
    $FileCreationInfo.URL = $File
    $Upload = $List.RootFolder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)
    $Context.Load($Upload)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
}
```